# how to keep pdf format while using itextSharp

Tags: itext

I am new in using itextsharp: i searched for how to keep pdf formatting while using itextsharp but found none. is there anything new about keeping pdf format in text?
please help. I want to keep format of page number and fonts of text headers and sub headers as in chapter heading etc

Comment: PDF is PDF. What do you mean when you say you want to keep PDF formatting? Seems like you don't really know much about the nature of PDF. For instance: are you talking about Tagged PDF or about unstructured PDF? In its current form, the question is invalid and it should be closed.

Comment: From that meager problem description I assume that you do something utterly wrong. You seem to try and edit a PDF by extracting its text and putting that plus changes into a new one. To edit PDFs you should instead use a PdfStamper. And you should really update your question so that others need not guess what you are talking about.